# Mongodb-Hadoop Adaptor

Tags: mongodb-hadoop

For getting started with the mongodb-hadoop adaptor i am referring to the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/)

The current hadoop version running on my system is 0.20.2.

So i edited the `build.sbt` file to

hadoopRelease in ThisBuild := "0.20.2".

But when i try the next command of "sbt package", i get the following error.

```
[error] Hadoop Release '%s' is an invalid/unsupported release.  Valid entries are in 0.20.2
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

The full log is

```
[info] Loading project definition from E:\softwares\mine\mongo-hadoop\project
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug]
[debug] Initial source changes:
[debug]         removed:Set()
[debug]         added: Set()
[debug]         modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug]
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]         product: Set()
[debug]         binary dep: Set()
[debug]         external source: Set()
[debug] Initially invalidated: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Hadoop Release '%s' is an invalid/unsupported release.  Valid entries are in 0.20.2
            at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
            at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(MongoHadoopBuild.scala:152)
            at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(MongoHadoopBuild.scala:152)
            at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:122)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.getOrElse(HashMap.scala:38)
            at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6.apply(MongoHadoopBuild.scala:152)
            at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6.apply(MongoHadoopBuild.scala:151)
            at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
            at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$single$1.apply(INode.scala:159)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$single$1.apply(INode.scala:159)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:177)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:132)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:64)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:73)
            at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:69)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    [error] Hadoop Release '%s' is an invalid/unsupported release.  Valid entries are in 0.20.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

hadoopRelease in ThisBuild := "0.20.2".

with

hadoopRelease in ThisBuild := "0.20".

For me it worked when I made 1.0.4 to 1.0.
Though I have to admit I did not check if the resutling jar worked.

EDIT: Jar did not work. Complained of some missing classes.